# Cartesian multiplication in SQL and update null columns

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables in MySQL database:

tbl_hashs >

| h_id | r_id | hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | xx |
| 2 | 123 | xx |

tbl_sandbox >

| h_id | r_id | hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | xx |

finally I want to have this table:

query result should be like >>>

| h_id | r_id | hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | xx |
| 1 | 123 | xx |
| 2 | 122 | xx |
| 2 | 123 | xx |

I think something like "Cartesian multiplication" can help me. but I can't do it in MySQL.
please somebody help me with proper query.

Comment: oh dude why table destructed?

Comment: you need an empty line before (and after) the table, it's a bug on SO (see: [Rendered view requires blank line before (and after) tables, but preview accepts both](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404376/rendered-view-requires-blank-line-before-and-after-tables-but-preview-accepts))

Comment: Subqueries like `SELECT DISTINCT` by each column separately then `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   t1.h_id,
   t2.r_id,
   t2.hash
FROM tbl_hashs t1
CROSS JOIN tbl_hashs t2
ORDER BY t1.h_id
```

But I did not use `tbl_sandbox`, is that good ?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32926caddc063c2adcbc03944ce489ce